# How to turn on debug mode with hypercorn.asyncio.serve(app,quart_cfg)

Tags: python, python-asyncio, telethon, quart, hypercorn

Have problem with using quart server with telethon library, but cannot handle the error. Trying to turn debug mode on, but it says that `Warning: The config` debug`has no affect when using serve warnings.warn("The config`debug `has no affect when using serve", Warning)`

Here is my code:

```
quart_cfg = hypercorn.Config()
quart_cfg.bind = ["0.0.0.0:8000"]
quart_cfg.debug = True
app = Quart(__name__)
...
async def main():
    await hypercorn.asyncio.serve(app,quart_cfg)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

How can i see logs from quart server? Maybe i can use something else rather than serve function? Cannot find any docs either..

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve the same affect as the debug flag by setting `loop.set_debug(debug)` as,

```
quart_cfg = hypercorn.Config()
quart_cfg.bind = ["0.0.0.0:8000"]
app = Quart(__name__)
...
async def main():
    await hypercorn.asyncio.serve(app,quart_cfg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.loop.set_debug(True)
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Thank you! It's helped for me!